# How to calculate tertiles in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that is not normally distributed and contains a lot of 0 values. I now want to calculate the tertiles for each column.

```
df <- tribble(
  ~shop,   ~products,  ~sales,  
    'A',      300,       100,                
    'B',      0,           0, 
    'C',      10,       2000, 
    'D',      0,           0, 
    'E',      0,           0, 
    'F',      0,           0, 
    'G',      20,         10, 
    'H',      0,           0, 
    'J',      700,        50, 
    'K',      0,           0, 
)
```

Thanks to @AlexB 's answer to that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62574146/how-to-create-tertile-in-r), I've tried calculating the tertiles with the following code:

```
df %>%
  arrange(products) %>% 
  mutate(tertiles = ntile(products, 3)) %>%
  mutate(tertiles = if_else(tertiles == 1, 'Low', if_else(tertiles == 2, 'Medium', 'High')))
```

However, even though the values are 0, the output is turning to 'high'. How can I calculate it more accurately?

Comment: Your `ifelse` contains the logical test `tertiles == 1` but you don't have a column called `tertiles` - did you mean `tertiles_products`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* what you're looking for could be achieved by using `cut` instead of `ntile`. Use the `breaks` argument in `cut` to define the limits for the three labels, and the `labels` argument to specify the labels themselves.

```r
df %>%
  arrange(products) %>% 
  mutate(tertile = cut(products, 
                       breaks = c(-1, 1, 100, Inf), 
                       labels = c("low", "medium", "high")))

#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>    shop  products sales tertile
#>    <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <fct>  
#>  1 B            0     0 low    
#>  2 D            0     0 low    
#>  3 E            0     0 low    
#>  4 F            0     0 low    
#>  5 H            0     0 low    
#>  6 K            0     0 low    
#>  7 C           10  2000 medium 
#>  8 G           20    10 medium 
#>  9 A          300   100 high   
#> 10 J          700    50 high
```

**Addendum**

To apply the same method to each column, we can do:

```r
f <- function(x) cut(x, c(-1, 1, 100, Inf), c("low", "medium", "high"))

df %>%
  arrange(products) %>% 
  mutate(across(c("products", "sales"), .fns = f, .names = "{.col}_tertile"))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>    shop  products sales products_tertile sales_tertile
#>    <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <fct>            <fct>        
#>  1 B            0     0 low              low          
#>  2 D            0     0 low              low          
#>  3 E            0     0 low              low          
#>  4 F            0     0 low              low          
#>  5 H            0     0 low              low          
#>  6 K            0     0 low              low          
#>  7 C           10  2000 medium           high         
#>  8 G           20    10 medium           medium       
#>  9 A          300   100 high             medium       
#> 10 J          700    50 high             medium
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks @Allan Cameron . I have many columns that I'd to calculate. Do you think there is a practical way to consider all columns instead of calculating seperately?

Comment: @datazang it depends on whether you need different breaks for each column. If the breaks and labels are all the same, it should be easy enough to do this using `mutate(across(...` - I'll add a demo

Comment: thanks a lot! But here, it orders all data by products column and classifies values based on 'products'. Am I wrong?

Comment: And just for better understanding: how did you decide to break data on the breaks c(-1, 1, 100, Inf)? @Allan Cameron

Comment: @datazang These are just my guesses about where you want the breaks to be. Less than 1 is low, 1-100 is medium, above 100 high.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

Somehow it is obvious that I was the first with the correct solution.
But Allan Cameron finished it perfectly. So this is okay as I learned many things from Allan Cameron:

To give my final solution:

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(c(products, sales), ~cut(., breaks = 3, labels = c("low", "medium", "high")), .names = "tertile_{.col}"))
```

```
  shop  products sales tertile_products tertile_sales
   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <fct>            <fct>        
 1 A          300   100 medium           low          
 2 B            0     0 low              low          
 3 C           10  2000 low              high         
 4 D            0     0 low              low          
 5 E            0     0 low              low          
 6 F            0     0 low              low          
 7 G           20    10 low              low          
 8 H            0     0 low              low          
 9 J          700    50 high             low          
10 K            0     0 low              low
```

**First answer:**
For column `products`:

```
df %>%
  arrange(products) %>% 
  mutate(tertiles = cut(products, breaks = 3, labels = c(1:3))) %>% 
  mutate(tertiles = case_when(tertiles==1 ~ "Low",
                              tertiles==2 ~ "Medium",
                              tertiles==3 ~ "High",
                              TRUE ~NA_character_))
```

```
   shop  products sales tertiles
   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   
 1 B            0     0 Low     
 2 D            0     0 Low     
 3 E            0     0 Low     
 4 F            0     0 Low     
 5 H            0     0 Low     
 6 K            0     0 Low     
 7 C           10  2000 Low     
 8 G           20    10 Low     
 9 A          300   100 Medium  
10 J          700    50 High
```

Comment: But why use case_when to convert 1:3 to labels rather than just using text labels directly?

Comment: Now back again. See my update. main thing is to use `cut`.